# Sequential downloading and playback of torrents on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bittorrent

I want to create my own server to download videos from a torrent sequentially and display them at the same time.

I'm going to start diving into this task with the [qBittorrent API](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-(qBittorrent-4.1)), and use it on the server to manage torrents.

As far as I understand, I can, just like on my home PC, set up a torrent file for sequential downloading, so that I will immediately receive a ready-made (but not yet fully downloaded) mp4 file, for example. Then I'm going to display this ready-made video file in streaming mode on a server with the Ruby on Rails framework. I assume that all interaction with qBittorrent will also take place through the Rails server.

My question is, do I understand and imagine the process correctly? Any ideas regarding the qBittorrent API? I'm still figuring out this API, so I'm not sure if it will work at all.

Any advice or direction would be helpful!